# Creating new pdMat classes for use in lme and nlme functions

Tags: r, nlme

I have been trying to find examples of anyone who has successfully created their own pdMat classes for use with the lme function in nlme.

Pinherio and Bates' book *Mixed effects models in S and S Plus* says:

"New pdMat classes, representing user-defined positive-definite matrix
structures, can be added to the set of standard classes in Table 4.3 and
used with the lme and nlme functions. For this, one must specify a constructor
function, generally with the same name as the class, and, at a
minimum, methods for the functions pdConstruct, pdMatrix, and coef. The
pdDiag constructor and methods can serve as templates for these."

I've tried examining the code but it is quite dense and not altogether obvious how the optimisation function restricts certain elements of the uninitialised matrices. Sifting through the literature on mixed models there does not seem to be any detailed info on anyone who has done this before.

Before I go trawling further through code of the methods for the premade functions I was wondering if anyone had come across examples where people have added new pdMat classes in the past?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, alas.  There are some `corStruct` extensions, e.g. in the `ape` package, but I'm not aware of `pdMat` extensions

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, I thought as much. Will try decipher the code for the built in structures and hope for the best!